# How to hide grand total from chart (ssrs over olap)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas, ssas-2008

I have a report in ssrs 2008, its data source is based on ssas.
I created a pie chart which shows total cost per shape. Dataset of the pie consists of only 4 fields.
Say i have 2 shapes, each of them has total cost. But in addition to that i also get a third slice in the pie which shows total of the other two.
How do i get rid of it?

Comment: Can you please supply the relevant columns of your Dataset with some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out luckily.
The problem was that my dataset returned the total, so i just filtered it in dataset filter expression.
I'm pretty sure there is a way not to return total inside dataset in the first place, if anyone knows, i will be glad to learn

Answer (score 0):

In your dataset you want to change the expression to [Dimension].[Hierarchy].[Attribute].members or [Dimension].[Hierarchy].children.  If you do [Dimension].[Hierarchy].members you will get the All member included.

Example: `[Date].[Month].members` will return each month plus the all member.  `[Date].[Month].[Month].members` will return the members without the All member.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful information. But in this case it's a little bit more complicated because i'm not actually selecting the date, date dimension appears only as a filter :  WHERE (tail(filter([Time].[Batch Time Stamp].Members, [Time].[Batch Time Stamp].CurrentMember),1).Item(0) ). In SELECT i have a date gange which i made based on time dimension. Well, as long as my report works..